# Coalescing operators in statically typed languages

Tags: c++, python

I'm not very acquainted with coalescing operators -- I just have an idea of what it exactly is from some Python usage.

As far as I'm concerned, a coalescing operator is a *blender* or *merger* operator that combines different expressions results into an unique value.

This expression in Python evaluates to `"some value"`:

```
value = True and "some value"
```

And this one is `False`:

```
value = False and "some value"
```

I could use some expression to be evaluated, instead of using bools directly, but in a statically typed language, like C++, this would not work -- unless with usage of templates, I guess.

My question is: is there any statically typed language that supports `coalescing operators`, or is the *evaluating expression problem* the reason why such languages do not support this feature?

Just to add some context, I've lately been trying to manipulate something close to those expressions in C++, but it always wind up into an `expected primary-expression before` error -- from what I inferred the problem is with the language typing method.

Comment: What is the `evaluating expression problem`?

Comment: @phant0m I thought having some "expression to be evaluated", instead of simply using a `True` or `False`, was the reason this feature can't be performed in C++, but it seems the reason is just due to the fact that C++ is statically typed -- and the same will apply to any other language with static typing.

Comment: You could get something close to what (I believe it is) you want in Haskell, which is statically typed.

Comment: @phant0m Does Haskell support coalescing operators? Even being statically typed?

Comment: "No", but you can implement it yourself, so I guess that's a "Yes". I'm no C++ expert, but I believe using regular function call syntax rather than an infix notation, you could get something similar to what can be done in Haskell. The only caveat is, that your values will need to be wrapped.

Comment: Since you've asked such a broad question, the answer isn't quite as straight-forward as people have implied here. C++ supports implicit type conversions, and can implicitly convert a derived type to a base type. `bool` and `const char *` don't have a common base type, so that conversion isn't possible. However, if your expression was: `bool value = true && someClassWithOperatorBoolDefined`, then it would work. C++ also supports something less concise, but similar in function to this coalescing idiom using the "ternary" operator (similar to python's `value = foo if test else bar`).

Comment: C++'s type system is intentionally strict-ish, but there are many useful "loopholes" that have proven to be very useful, some of which have been improved upon by the standard due to demand (static assertions, SFINAE, lambdas, explicit casts, and covariant return types, to name a few).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

C++ is not Python (or PHP or some other "higher level language"). In Python, a variable can change from containing a boolean to containing a string to containing a float. In C and C++, a variable is declared to contain a specific type. There are ways that you can store different types in the same structure, e.g. "Boost::variant", which does something similar to what Python does internally - it has a "what type is this variable" inside the data structure.

Comment: I understand C++ is not Python, and I assume "what type is this variable" Boost provides is somehow a reflection approach, right? But, is the reason `coalescing operators` don't work in C++ due to the language typing method -- statically/dynamically typed?

Comment: Yes, if you have a static type, then you have no way that you can assign values of different types [that aren't compatible types] to the same variable.